# first letter displaying as Higher than other letters in print media

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: that is a print preview of my page]

My page displays normal on the screen, but when I want to print, it comes up this way shown in the image. I am using bootstrap 4 and below are code lines for the elements captured in the image.

```
<h3 class="text-center">RESULT SHEET</h3>
<!-- for the table -->
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="7" class="text-center">COGNITIVE ASSESSMENT</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

how do I get the texts "RESULT SHEET" and "COGNITIVE ASSESSMENT" to display properly in a straight line as it should.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this in media print

```
@media print{
        ::first-letter {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
    }
}
```